# geoCouch install: compiling failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchdb, geocouch

I have trouble with including geoCouch to running couchDB (1.6.1).

I followed the Instruction: https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/#for-apache-couchdb

In the GeoCouch directory (`$HOME/geocouch`) I tried to compile:

```
COUCH_SRC=$HOME/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src/couchdb make couchdb
```

and get the message:

```
/rebar -C rebar_couchdb.config compile
==> vtree (compile)
Compiling /home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl failed:

/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:16: can't find include file "couch_db.hrl"
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:41: undefined macro 'LOG_DEBUG/2'
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:18: function cleanup/2 undefined
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:26: spec for undefined function vtree_cleanup:cleanup/2
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:47: function cleanup_multiple/3 is unused
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:54: function cleanup_nodes/2 is unused
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:62: function member_of_nodes/2 is unused
/home/ec2-user/geocouch/vtree/src/vtree_cleanup.erl:75: function partition_nodes/3 is unused
```

"couch_db.hrl" is located in /home/ec2-user/apache-couchdb-1.6.1/src/couchdb

Does anyone know how to fix that? Help/idea?

Comment: It was a bug that should be fixed now.

Comment: @vmx: works fine for me now, yeah thanks.